# Where is the Ansible's template module?

Tags: python, ansible

The template module is a core ansible module. There is a file called template.py in: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/files/template.py

But, it has just the following comment and some documentation:

```
# this is a virtual module that is entirely implemented server side
```

What does it mean? Which server? Isn't ansible module a generic construct with a main() entry point and standard params.

Answer (score 2):

Might be, they mixed up server/client in that comment. Ansible modules are run on the target host. The template "module" though seems to be implemented as a local  action plugin. This seems to be the file: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/v2/ansible/plugins/action/template.py

There is not much server side action involved. The template gets rendered locally and then the `file` module is called to transfer the rendered content to the remote host.

Answer (score 2):

[udondan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2753241/udondan) is correct, the template task is implemented as an action plugin; currently the link to find a recent version seems to be https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/template.py. Hope this helps anyone out there looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

In stable-1.9 it is here, and the verify step is implemented by the copy module.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-1.9/lib/ansible/runner/action_plugins/template.py#L157